# How to combine two dicts in one with replacing "false" values in first by "not false" values from second if values are not in false_list (Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, merge

The problem in that:
I have two Excel sheets. Need to replace values in [something, like, some, false, values] in first sheet by values from second. The tables can contain not equal dimensions

For example, need that **dc_result** from **dc1** and **dc2**, by merging **on='n'**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


dc1 = {
    'n':[1, 2, 3, 4],
    'a':[0, 5, 0.0, 'A'],
    'b':[0,'', False, 'B', 'C'],
    }

dc2 = {
    'n':[1, 2, 3],
    'a':[1, 0, 3],
    'b':[6, 5, 8],
    'c':[6, 5],
    }

# df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dc1)
# df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dc2)
# df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer', on='n')

false_list = [False, 0, 0.0, 'Nan', np.nan, None, '','Null']

dc_result = {
    'n':[1, 2, 3, 4],
    'a':[1, 5, 3, 'A'],
    'b':[6, 5, 8, 'B', 'C'],
    'c':[6, 5],
    }

 # or

dc_result_2 = {
    'n':[1, 2, 3, 4, ''],
    'a':[1, 5, 3, 'A', ''],
    'b':[6, 5, 8, 'B', 'C'],
    'c':[6, 5, '', '', ''],
    }

print(dc_result)
```

any panda's way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since pandas doesn't like columns with unequal length, this can instead be done using a python dictionary/list comprehension

```
dc_result = {k:[dc1[k][i] if dc1[k][i] not in false_list else dc2[k][i] 
             for i in range(len(dc1[k]))] for k in dc1}
```

Comment: Bro, it's brilliance. Small questions is how then convert it in df by df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dc_result) for using in pandas, any way?